# Python PriorityQueue order

Tags: python, priority-queue

I'm trying to figure out in what order PriorityQueue.get() returns values in Python. First I thought that the smaller priority values get returned first but after few examples it's not like that. This is the example that I have run:

```
>>> qe = PriorityQueue()
>>> qe.put("Br", 0)
>>> qe.put("Sh", 0.54743812441605)
>>> qe.put("Gl", 1.1008112004388)

>>> qe.get()
'Br'
>>> qe.get()
'Gl'
>>> qe.get()
'Sh'
```

Why is it returning values in this order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html), the first parameter is priority, and second - is value. So that's why you get such result.

> A typical pattern for entries is a tuple in the form: (priority_number, data).

So you should pass a tuple to put like this:

```
>>> q = PriorityQueue()
>>> q.put((10,'ten'))
>>> q.put((1,'one'))
>>> q.put((5,'five'))
>>> q.get()
>>> (1, 'one')
>>> q.get()
>>> (5, 'five')
>>> q.get()
>>> (10, 'ten')
```

Notice additional braces.

Comment: But if I do (priority_number, data) then .get() returns priority_number and I want it to return data